# Send json object to local php server using HttpURLConnection

Tags: php, android

I am trying to send json object in android to local php server(XAMPP).
Here is my php script which recieves that object.

```
<?php

  $response = array();

  if (isset(($_POST['PNR_NO'])&&($_POST['Status'])&&($_POST['update_time']))){

      $PNR_NO = $_POST['PNR_NO'];
      $Status = $_POST['Status'];
      $update_time = $_POST['update_time'];

      // include db connect class
      require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

      // connecting to db
      $db = new DB_CONNECT();

      // mysql inserting a new row
      $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pnr_database(PNR_NO, Status,update_time) VALUES('$PNR_NO', '$Status', '$update_time')");

      // check if row inserted or not
      if ($result) {
          // successfully inserted into database
          $response["success"] = 1;
          $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

          // echoing JSON response
          echo json_encode($response);
      }
      else {
          // failed to insert row
          $response["success"] = 0;
          $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

          // echoing JSON response
          echo json_encode($response);
      }
  }
  else {
      $response["success"] = 0;
      $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

      echo json_encode($response);
   }?>
```

And the java code that i am using is :

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        OutputStream os;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            //constants
            String pnr = "1234";
            String stat = "WC12";
            String updTime = "13:20";
            Log.i("aaaaa", "Started");
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("PNR_NO",pnr );
            jsonObject.put("Status", stat);
            jsonObject.put("update_time", updTime);
            String message = jsonObject.toString();
            System.out.println(message);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /*milliseconds*/);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(message.getBytes().length);


            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
            conn.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

            //open
            conn.connect();

            //setup send
            os = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            os.write(message.getBytes());
            Log.i("aaaaa","ended");
            //clean up
            os.flush();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (JSONException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {

            //clean up

        /*try {
            os.close();
            is.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        */
            conn.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Basically I want to send data to my php server where I have created a database which has a table named pnr_database and the sent data should get stored in that table.I don't want any response from server.

But my code is not working...

I tested my php script from a html form where i was sending data to server... In that case php script was working fine and data was getting stored in database But i am not able to make it work in android.

Comment: Please define your **Code is not working**. It's not possible to guess the issue just with the code.

Comment: Replace your php script by var_dump($_POST); statement only. Read the response and tell what is dumped.

Comment: There is no error from server side and my input values are also not getting added to the table... I am also not able to identify my error.

Comment: You are not reading the echos from your php script now. Then why do you have them? Read them from the inputstream. With the var dump you can check if you posted the data well and if it was received ok by the php script. You should first pay attention to the posting and receiving of the data. The insert in the database comes later.

Comment: 'Here is my php script which recieves that object.'. No that does not look like receiving json text. That will not work in this way. But try the var dump first to see.

Comment: Sorry i am not able to understand..In my PHP code.. where should i add this var_dump ($_POST) Statement.

Comment: I am just a beginner

Comment: Replace! Not add. Instead off. Only that line. Remove or comment all oher code.

Comment: I/aaaaa: Started
I/System.out: {"update_time":"13:20","Status":"WC12","PNR_NO":"1234"}
I/aaaaa: ended

Comment: There should be the word Array in it. What happened?

Comment: i got something like this in logcat of Android Studio

Comment: No it is exactly like this... URL that i am using to call this function is "http://10.0.2.2/create_product.php" Is there any error??

Comment: The html form which i was using to test my php script shows  array(3) { ["PNR_NO"]=> string(4) "1234" ["Status"]=> string(4) "WC12" ["update_time"]=> string(5) "13:20" } in browser  indicating my php script to be somewhat correct...

Comment: You should add the code which writes that in your logcat to your post. So we can see what happens. You did not add the code to read the echos from the inputstream. Add that code too.

Comment: If you test your php script with a html form then why do you try to send json with your Android client. Makes no sense.

Comment: 'my php script shows array(3)...'. I think it echos Array(3)...

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late answer. But the JSON you receive in php is encoded so you need to decode it as such in your if clause:

```
$decoded = json_decode($_POST, true); //this will return an array
$PNR_NO = $decoded['PNR_NO'];
$Status = $decoded['Status'];
$update_time = $decoded['update_time'];
```

Here you can enter the columns to your table.